# Run an xinput command when a device is connected?

Tags: python, bluetooth, xinput

Due to a bug in the kernel driver for the Apple Magic Trackpad, two finger right click doesn't work by default. However, you can fix the issue by running the following:

```
xinput set-prop $DEVICE_ID "Synaptics Click Action" 1 3 2
```

...where `$DEVICE_ID` is the device id given for the device in the output of `xinput --list`.

Due to the nature of the device (Bluetooth) it's not always connected. Can I run this fix script every time that `xinput` detects the device as connected?

Comment: Did you find the answer to that?